# Entity Framework: how to execute stored procedure with multiple parameters passed as an array

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have two functions for running stored procedures, one returns a collection, and one just simply executes a stored procedure.

The first one that returns a collection works perfectly and has been tested with plenty of parameters in the array:

```
public ICollection<TObject> RunStoredProcedure_ReturnCollection_Generic(string spName, List<string> paramFields, List<string> paramFieldValues)
{
    string queryStr = "exec " + spName;
    List<SqlParameter> pars = new List<SqlParameter>();

    if (paramFields != null)
    {
        for (int i=0; i <= (paramFields.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter();
            par.ParameterName = paramFields[i];
            par.Value = paramFieldValues[i];
            pars.Add(par);

            if (queryStr.Contains("@"))
            { 
                queryStr = queryStr + ","; 
            }

            queryStr = queryStr + " @" + par.ParameterName;   
        }

        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<TObject>(queryStr, pars.ToArray()).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<TObject>("exec " + spName).ToList();
    }
}
```

My second function, which simply should execute and has nothing to return does not work and I can't understand why:

```
public void ExecuteProcedure_Generic(string spName, List<string> paramFields, List<string> paramFieldValues)
{
    string queryStr = "exec " + spName;
    List<SqlParameter> pars = new List<SqlParameter>();

    if (paramFields != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (paramFields.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter();
            par.ParameterName = paramFields[i];
            par.Value = paramFieldValues[i];
            pars.Add(par);

            if (queryStr.Contains("@"))
            { 
                queryStr = queryStr + ","; 
            }

            queryStr = queryStr + " @" + par.ParameterName;
        }

        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(queryStr, pars.ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(spName);
    }
}
```

The error that I get on the `ExecuteSqlCommand` line is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Procedure or function 'TidyTempTableByUserID' expects parameter '@UserID', which was not supplied

I have trapped the code and the `queryStr` looks to be an identical format as in my previous working function, and of course the `pars` array is populated with both parameters and their values. `queryStr` at the time of execution reads:

```
exec Orders_OrderLineStaging_Append @UserID, @MealPlanID
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `Orders_OrderLineStaging_Append`  procedure directly or indirectly  calls `TidyTempTableByUserID` and this call is in error.

Comment: Thanks @Serg, Ah, you're right. This is a an additional Stored Procedure inside the first one, and it needs a second parameter I am not supplying. So, the error is in the Stored Procedure itself. Many thanks!